# Toggle next table

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is throwing me for a loop. So I want to be able to only slideToggle the very next `<table>` on the page. Now I have tried everything, but its not working and I'm out of ideas.

Here is the link to the code:

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wsfj1cqe/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-step').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().next('table').slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle(0);
    });
});

<div class="table-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"> 
            <a class="toggle-step">Toggle Table <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block;"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `.parent()` only goes up one level in the DOM

Comment: That begs the question could I have done .parent().next().next() ?

Comment: No , because .parent() gets you from the anchor to the list item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('ul').next('table').slideToggle("fast");
```

Because the parent of your link isn't the sibling of the table, you need to modify your DOM traversal. And because the list isn't a parent of the link, you need to use `closest()`.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsfj1cqe/3/)**

Comment: Well sure enough, that worked. I can't begin to tell you all the combinations I tried, never thought do to .closest('ul')